# Different number of samples inside .csv when exploring with Excel and Pandas

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

I'm new to pandas and data science in general. I am currently exploring a dataset using pandas.

I've noticed that by opening it with Excel, it shows that there are 130.808 rows, subtracting the header makes it 130.807, but if I open the same file using pandas
`df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep='|', header=0)` 
and calling .shape property it shows that it only has 130.802 samples.

Where did the other 5 disappear if I did not make any modifications to the dataset?

Not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm using Anaconda distribution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the values has quotechar, and if not does values in dataset contains lineterminator.

If no quotechar is prodived/included in dataset, a lineterminator character in values can cause program to think this is a new row, instead of a newline in a box

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, description column contained delimiting signs as well..